# What causes runlevel (to lvl 0)

Tags: linux, reboot

What can cause my system to hit runlevel 0 during normal operations?

```
shutdown system down  2.6.32-042stab11 Thu Dec 24 13:53 - 21:47 (1+07:54)
runlevel (to lvl 0)   2.6.32-042stab11 Thu Dec 24 13:52 - 13:53  (00:00)
```

The only this that comes close is a weekly reboot, but not at that time.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 3 * * 0 /sbin/reboot
```

**Edit** : 
Entries from syslog

```
Dec 24 13:52:59 vps86036 shutdown[21191]: shutting down for system halt
Dec 24 13:52:59 vps86036 init: Switching to runlevel: 0
```

**Edit 2** : `uname -srv` output

```
Linux 2.6.32-042stab111.12 #1 SMP Thu Sep 17 11:38:20 MSK 2015
```

Comment: Runlevel 0 means that the system rebooted. Is this a physical machine or a VPS/cloud instance? In addition to the snippet of output from `last`, do you have the system logs for that time?

Comment: This is a VPS, I addded the syslog entries from that time

Comment: Could you also add the output of `uname -srv`?

Comment: Then the host probably requested the reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record this VPS was forcibly rebooted by the provider.
Sometimes you just wish you could attach slaps to emails.